Issues using the captureVisibleTab API from side panel
I'm trying to build an chrome extension that captures and displays screen shots using a global side panel.
I've managed to successfully use the following code from a popup. However when I migrate the same code across to run from a side panel I'm getting what appears to be permission errors.
I've included the code below.
(I did manage to get the screengrab to work momentarily from the side panel, but it stopped when I reloaded the extension and I haven't been able to replicate it since.)
manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "SidePanel - Screenshot Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Shows how to call sidePanel.open() to open a global side panel.",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "116",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service-worker.js"
  },
  "side_panel": {
    "default_path": "sidepanel-global.html"
  },
"permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "windows", "sidePanel", "contextMenus"],
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon-16.png",
    "48": "images/icon-48.png",
    "128": "images/icon-128.png"
  },

  "action": {
    "default_title": "Launch DoDid"
  }

}

sidepanel-global.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Screenshot Extension</title>
  <script src="screenshot.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="capture">Capture Screenshot</button>
  <div id="screenshotContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>

screenshot.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const captureButton = document.getElementById("capture");
    const screenshotContainer = document.getElementById("screenshotContainer");
  
    captureButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(function(screenshotDataUrl) {
        const screenshotImage = new Image();
        screenshotImage.src = screenshotDataUrl;
        screenshotContainer.appendChild(screenshotImage);
      });
    });
  });


I get the following error messages:
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Either the '<all_urls>' or 'activeTab' permission is required.


It's issue of activeTab permission in side panel.
You can use it with "<all_urls"> by adding on manifest. "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
Check this links.
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/uTtfM3Xbc3U/m/N-NBEAGuAQAJ
https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40916430
